# Prevent double border from responsive columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, border

Imagine you are using Bootstrap 4 and printing some cells. Cell numbers are unpredictable.

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
</div>
```

When you run code, you see "double" borders. If I use nth-child selector, **I have to calculate every breakpoint**, because on specific breakpoint it shows different cells per row. How you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `border-right`/`border-bottom` with your element and use `border-top`/`border-left` with the container:

```css
.cell {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
</div>
```

With fewer cells you can try this *hack* with pseudo elements:

```css
.cell {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.row {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
  overflow:hidden; /*hide the overflow*/
  padding-top:1px; /*for the top border*/
}


/*top border for all*/
.cell:first-child:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  left:0;
  height:1px;
  width:100vw;
  background:#000;
}
/*hide the unwated top border in case of few cells*/
.cell:last-child:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  left:calc(100% + 1px);
  height:1px;
  width:100vw;
  background:#fff;
}

/*avoid issue with stacking context and 
be sure the cells are on the top of the pseudo element*/
.cell:first-child,
.cell:last-child {
  z-index:auto;
}

/*for one cell*/
.cell:first-child:last-child {
  border-top:1px solid;
}

.cell:first-child:last-child:before {
  content:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
</div>

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
</div>

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">cell</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try on fewer cells. You see unwanted border top.

Comment: Almost completed. Only issue now is its failing when there are only 1 cell.

Answer (score 4):

You can handle it like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/u5dCBDg1he

```
.row {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px  0   0  1px;
}

.cell {
    border-color: black;    
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0  1px 1px  0;
}
```

This adds a top & left border to the entire `row`, and then right & bottom margins to each `cell`. You can also accomplish this using the border utility classes.

```
<div class="row no-gutters border-left border-top">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 border-bottom border-right">cell</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried your trick already. But it won't work perfectly. Try it on fewer columns. You see unwanted border top.

Comment: Yes, that's an issue I haven't figured out but it looks like @TemaniAfif answer will work.